# How to intercept child control mouse wheen messages

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mousewheel, wtl

I need to get mouse wheel events in frame window but they are caught by child windows. How can I redirect mouse wheel messages from all child windows to this window?

Answer (score 2):

It is already done for you out of the box. Make sure you don't prevents things from rolling the usual way.

[WM_MOUSEWHEEL message (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Sent to the focus window when the mouse wheel is rotated. **The DefWindowProc function propagates the message to the window's parent.** There should be no internal forwarding of the message, since DefWindowProc propagates it up the parent chain until it finds a window that processes it.